# Calling async function within Tornado overriden methods

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, tornado, kafka-python

I am trying to call async functions in tornado overriden methods.
Initially, the function `generate()` is syncronous, but that seems to block the entire program, including `on_connection_close` method

```
class Reader:
  
    def __init__(self, topic, group_id):
        self.topic = topic
        self.consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers="kafka:9092",
                                         group_id=group_id)

    async def read(self, sender):
        print("enter read...")
        #it seems the code below is blocking
        await self.consumer.start()
        async for message in self.consumer:      
            sender(json.dumps(consumed_message))
            await self.consumer.commit()
```

```
class SampleSockeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):


    def on_connection_close(self):
        self.app.close()

    def on_message(self, message):
        generate(message)
        #await generate(message)

    async def generate(self, message):
      
        await self.reader.read(message)
```

`print("enter read...")` is only executed once in the first `read()` call. In the subsequent `read()` calls, it does not print anymore.
Now when I comment out all the code below it i.e

```
await self.consumer.start()
        async for message in self.consumer:      
            sender(json.dumps(consumed_message))
            await self.consumer.commit()
```

it works again

How do I fix this problem? Shouldn't it be an async call?

```
async def main():

    app = Application()

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: *"I tried to mark on_message to be async, but that does not work."* - can you post that attempt?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I did further testing, and found the potential cause. But I am not sure why await within an async function not work

Answer (score 0):

`on_message()` can be coroutine and has to be `async` if you use `await generate(message)`.

https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.on_message